# Spark Scala FoldLeft resulting in StackOverflow when run in the cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark, stack-overflow, foldleft

Im using the following code in order to re-shape a dataframe using its rows for this reshaping.

The dataframe contains the date of when a product changes its ID, but in order to join it with a huge other dataframe containing the transactions, I need a new column which defines the valid ID range.

For instance, if product A changes to be product B effective day 01/01, and then changes to be product C effective 03/01, I will need the start date and end date in the same row so I can join it with the huge transactions dataframe filtering by the dates that the product is effectively B (or C), so I can properly rename the products to their effective real ID.

Another piece of information, df_MPC is about 800 lines, and will not grow much more.

So the approach I am trying (which works when run in the development environment) is to foldleft.

The summarized version of the MPC dataframe would be:

```
Product | Date      | NewProd
A       | 01/01/2018| B
B       | 03/01/2018| C
```

Objective:

```
Product | Date      | NewProd | OriginalProd | EndDate
A       | 01/01/2018| B       | A            | 03/01
B       | 03/01/2018| C       | A            | 31/12-9999
```

(OriginalProd column being neccesary for the final join with the transactions dataframe)

And the code resulting in stackoverflow is as follows:

```
var rowList = new ListBuffer[Row]()
val it = df_MPC_SOURCE.toLocalIterator()
while (it.hasNext) { rowList += it.next()}

val df_MPC_TRANSFORMED = rowList.reverse
  .foldLeft(df_MPC_pre_edit_source: DataFrame)((acc, elem) => acc
    .withColumn("EndDate",
      when((col("N_DISTRIBUTOR_CODE") === elem.getAs("N_DISTRIBUTOR_CODE"))
        && col("N_CONTRACT_CODE") === elem.getAs("N_CONTRACT_CODE")
        && (col("N_PRODUCT_ID_NEW") === elem.getAs("N_PRODUCT_ID")),
        elem.getAs("D_EFFECTIVE_CHANGE"))
        .otherwise(col("EndDate")))
    .withColumn("OriginalProd",
      when((col("N_DISTRIBUTOR_CODE") === elem.getAs("N_DISTRIBUTOR_CODE"))
        && col("N_CONTRACT_CODE") === elem.getAs("N_CONTRACT_CODE")
        && (col("MPC_original") === elem.getAs("N_PRODUCT_ID_NEW")),
        elem.getAs("N_PRODUCT_ID"))
        .otherwise(col("OriginalProd")))
  )
```

This code transforms the source dataframe (example provided above) into the objective dataframe (example above too).

It does so by iterating through all its 800 lines in a sorted fashion (datewise) and for each of its rows:

- Change the valid date for all the products that match that given line
- Update the original product ID in the case we find an intermediate
  product. For instance, if we have a product that swaps from ID "A" to
  "B" and from "B" to "C" later in time, we will need the column with
  the original product ID ("A" in this case) for been able to join our
  result with the original transactions table, which will only contain
  the product ID "A".

And the error thrown when this code is used in the cluster:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at scala.collection.GenSetLike$class.apply(GenSetLike.scala:44)
        at scala.collection.AbstractSet.apply(Set.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(TreeNode.scala:334)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:333)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
```

How could I make this code work in the cluster same way it works properly locally?
Thank you!

Comment: `StackOverFlow` error means that at some point your program is creating a chain of function calls too long to fit in the allocated stack size.

Comment: And what is this code? Why are you using converting the DataFrame to a `List` ?

Comment: The purpose is to iterate all the (800) rows of the dataframe in order to transform the summariced MPC df (example provided) into the objective (example provided). I will update the question with a more detailed explanation asap.

Comment: So... the rows are just 800 ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh and how could that code be working locally but result in a StackOverflow in a cluster? Is there any specific parameter (heap memory, swap, ...) that could be limiting the resources in the cluster and resulting in this error?

Comment: Yes, 800 rows, and in my humble machine works :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a while to figure out what you were trying to do. I think you can do the same with a simpler approach.

This doesn't explain why your code doesn't work but your *foldleft* can be replace with a spark sql query, something like this:

```
df_MPC_SOURCE.registerTempTable("mpc_source")

val test = sqlContext.sql(
  """select c1.N_PRODUCT_ID,c1.D_EFFECTIVE_CHANGE,c1.N_PRODUCT_ID_NEW,
    |coalesce(c2.D_EFFECTIVE_CHANGE,c1.MPC_endDate) as MPC_endDate,
    |coalesce(c3.N_PRODUCT_ID,c1.MPC_original) as MPC_original
    |from mpc_source c1
    |left join mpc_source c2 on c1.N_DISTRIBUTOR_CODE=c2.N_DISTRIBUTOR_CODE
    |and c1.N_CONTRACT_CODE=c2.N_CONTRACT_CODE
    |and c1.N_PRODUCT_ID_NEW=c2.N_PRODUCT_ID
    |left join mpc_source c3 on c1.N_DISTRIBUTOR_CODE=c3.N_DISTRIBUTOR_CODE
    |and c1.N_CONTRACT_CODE=c3.N_CONTRACT_CODE
    |and c1.MPC_original = c3.N_PRODUCT_ID_NEW
  """.stripMargin)
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Awesome! Tested it and works both in the cluster and in the local IDE (Intellij). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would check the differences in Spark executor configs on local machine and cluster. It might be the case that number of threads (tasks/cores) created on local machines may be less that number of tasks being created in an executor in cluster. Decreasing numbers of cores per executor will reduce the number of threads created in an executor jvm and so the space taken by thread stack. Alternatively, you can try increasing memory per executor. it would be good to keep the configuration of executors same on both the machine and then see if the problem reproduces.